# Youtube API controls leaves a black portion of screen

Tags: html, css, video, youtube, youtube-api

I am using the YouTube API  as the following:

```
<script>
  // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
  // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      playerVars: { 'modestbranding': 1, 'showinfo' : 0,  'controls': 0 },
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE'
    });
  }
</script>
```

I have a div that is named player on my html.
I need the video to not have the controls (controls=0). The problem is whenever I remove the controls instead of them there is a black bar. Instead of that black bar replacing the controls, I want the video to expand and take the whole video's height&width.
Am I missing anything here? Thanks for any light on that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your 'playerVars' :

```
'autoplay' : 0
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't change a thing about the black screen.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the video dimensions doesn't match the values of your variables.

This looks better (e.g. height: '360'):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>YT - Test</title>
    <script>
  // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
  // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '360',
      width: '640',
      playerVars: { 'modestbranding': 1, 'showinfo' : 0,  'controls': 0 },
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE'
    });
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ytplayer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please see https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo